# Weird error after updating package.json of old project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, babeljs

Updated the packages.json of a old project to work on it and get this weird error. I don't even know what the issue is here. Any help is appreciated!

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/inherits.js 1:0-46

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './setPrototypeOf' in 'C:\Users--\Desktop\Lowkey Meal - React\client\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\esm'
Did you mean 'setPrototypeOf.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './setPrototypeOf' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2.js 1:0-46

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './defineProperty' in 'C:\Users--\Desktop\Lowkey Meal - React\client\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\esm'
Did you mean 'defineProperty.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './defineProperty' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutProperties.js 1:0-74

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './objectWithoutPropertiesLoose' in 'C:\Users--\Desktop\Lowkey Meal - React\client\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\esm'
Did you mean 'objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './objectWithoutPropertiesLoose' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "updated `package.json`"?

Comment: @NathanWiles Updated all the dependencies to the latest versions

Comment: @rody401 I am having the same problems, I think it has to do with compatibility of the packages, but have not figured out how to solve it yet.

Comment: Having the same issue. Any update? @Sachihiro

Answer (score 3):

Had similar problem when upgrading my `package.json` with `create-react-app` `5.0.0`.

I'd already tried deleting `node-modules` and re-doing the `npm install` but it didn't work.

The trick was to delete `node_modules` AND `package-lock.json` before doing the npm install. After that the build worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just type in terminal --> npm i --> press Enter
Required module is not installed and after running this command all the required module will be installed automatically.

Comment: I have already done that, it didn't work :( I then removed all dependencies and reinstalled it, still didn't work. When I start the server, it says "webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 18 errors in 7802 ms".